# How to pass an unix command with white spaces to a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, port, command-line-arguments

C# program is calling a shell script with one argument. The argument is an unix command:

```
port="/dev/ttyUSB0";
procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("sudo", "sh test.sh " + 
"$(udevadm info - a - n " + port + " | grep '{serial}' | head - 
n1)");
```

My shell script is **test.sh**:

```
echo $@
```

It prints the above command:

```
$(udevadm info - a - n /dev/ttyUSB0 | grep '{serial}' | head - n1)
```

but not the expected result.

Please help. How to run this command

Comment: What *is* the expected result?

Comment: something like     ATTRS{serial}=="A5052G97"

Comment: The arguments are passed as-is, simply because you're not running a shell. The command-substitution with `$(...)` is a shell-thing. Instead of running `sudo` run `bash` with the `-c` argument to execute a command.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `sh -c "COMMAND"`. `COMMAND` can be a pipe and supports all kinds of redirection. It works like entering the COMMAND in a shells command line. You have only to escape `"` by `\"`. Also `$` inside single quotes must be escaped.

`sh -c 'COMMAND'` (single quotes around `COMMAND`) is an alternative, if not using a single quote in `COMMAND` and you don't want to expand `$`.

btw, use `$@` always in double quotes `"$@"`. Otherwise a word split at spaces is done.